# Enviar datos de formulario con tabla HTML(varios registros) a controlador MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, html, mvc

Buen día.
Trabajo en un proyecto MVC C# y tengo un modelo que representa una tabla en mi base de datos, el modelo a continuación solo representa algunas propiedades de mi clase para no crearles confusión y representan los datos de un único Evento, los datos de una única Empresa y los datos de todos los empleados que la empresa quiera registrar al evento, así:

```
 public class Ejemplo
    {
        // datos de la empresa
        [Required]
        public string Empresa { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string telefonoEmpresa { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string NumeroPatronalEmpresa { get; set; }

        //Datos del evento
        [Required]
        public string CodEvento { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string NombreEvento { get; set; }

        // Datos del empleado
        [Required]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Cargo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Salario { get; set; }
    }
```

en mi controller[HttpGet] solamente creo la vista

```
 public ActionResult ObtenerSolicitudCapacitacion() {
            return View();
        }
```

y la vista esta fuertemente tipada con la clase anterior

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora mi vista contiene los datos del evento, de la empresa y quiero que pueda inscribir tatos empleados como desee la empresa al evento, para ello los dos últimos campos de mi modelo se pueden especificar las veces que la empresa desee en el mismo formulario, es decir que en la vista:
Una empresa puede inscribir cuantos empleados desee a un Único evento en una misma solicitud.

Para presentar los empleados que la empresa va inscribiendo he creado una tabla HTML muy sencilla que una vez la empresa especifica los datos del emleado presiona un boton y mediante jQUery agrego los datos a la tabla

```
@*dato de empleado a mostrar en la tabla HTML*@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cargo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", id = "inputText1" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cargo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cargo)
            </div>
        </div>

        @*dato de empleado a mostrar en la tabla HTML*@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salario, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", id = "inputText2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salario)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Salario)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="cargarTabla">Ingresar Empleado</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

y mi jQuery que agrega a la tabla la informacion definida en los input es el siguiente

```
 $("#cargarTabla").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var salario = $("#inputText1").val().toLowerCase();
        var cargo = $("#inputText2").val();

        $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr><td for="salario">' + salario + '</td><td for="cargo">' + cargo + '</td><td><a href="#" id="select">Modificar</a><a href="#" id="eliminar">  Eliminar</a></td></tr>');
        $("#inputText1").val('');
        $("#inputText2").val('');
        $("#inputText3").val('');
        $('#inputText1').focus();
    });
```

ahora tendré los datos de un único evento, una única empresa y varios empleados de la empresa(cuyos datos estan en la tabla HTML) en mi formulario y quiero enviar todos esos datos a mi controller que imagino deberá recibir List, podrían indicarme como debo mandar la información a mi controller por favor.

Answer (score -1):

Desde mi punto de vista no es necesario que envíes toda la información del empleado y al mismo tiempo enviar toda la lista (*a menos que exista un motivo muy específico para realizarlo aunque tampoco lo haría de ninguna forma así*). Lo que tienes que hacer en un inicio es asociar el empleado a una empresa, por ejemplo, tu modelo debería estar de la siguiente forma:

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Una vez que se tiene la información capturada, y le das clic al botón <kbd>Submit</kbd> debe llegar la información al `Controller`, la cual se guarda tal cual en la base de datos.

Ahora, dependiendo del manejo de las vistas, recomendaría que la parte inferior la generes como una vista parcial, de esta forma, una vez que se registró el empleado en el evento se actualicé la vista parcial con la información de todos los empleados registrados.

Visual Studio genera las vistas de manera automática basándote en el modelo como  clase base y seleccionando un *template* para crear, eliminar, ver una lista etc. Por ejemplo, para la vista del registro quedaría algo así:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.EmployeeModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>EmployeeModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Section, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Section, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Section, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Y la vista parcial de los usuarios registrados sería algo así:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.EmployeeModel>

<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeCode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Section)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Finalmente, tendrás toda la información de los empleados asociados a alguna empresa, con eso, tu información será consistente sin la necesidad de realizar acciones al *vuelo*.

Comment: Hola, Gracias por la respuesta, mi plan era utilizar vistas parciales pero (a lo mejor estoy equivocado) quiero que la informacion referente a empresa(cinco campos y evento(siete campos) se envie de "una vez" con la informacion de todos los empleados definidos en la tabla, para ello tengo un solo modelo en el cual efectivamente como tu me explicas tengo definido las propiedades de la empresa y del evento(en total (siete campos evento + cinco campos empresa+ seis campos empleado)) y quisera enviar esa informacion a mi controller ya sea con $.ajax o enviando el modelo directamente al controller

Comment: solo agregar que l ainformacion d ela empresa y el evento se definen una vez y que al evento la empresa puede enviar muchos empleados

Comment: Bueno, si pusieras la información con la que cuentas actualmente sería más sencillo determinar una solución, en conjunto con las vistas, sean o no parciales. Por lo que logro entender no es un tema nada complicado, la solución será sencilla pero se requieren detalles adicionales :)

Comment: Excelente, creo que deberé crear otro thread para postear el código, podría avisarte por aca y pasarte el link talvez tengas tiempo y me ayudas ?

Comment: Claro, con gusto, pero, ¿si ya tienes esta pregunta abierta no sería mejor editarla? bueno, es mi opinión, de cualquier forma ahí estaremos apoyando a la comunidad :)

Comment: Tienes razón, colocaré el código acá

Comment: Listo Flxtr, modifique la pregunta y muestro el código, podrías ayudarme?

Comment: @PabloTobar dame oportunidad de analizar las ediciones que realizaste y vemos qué solución podemos aplicar :)

Comment: muy bien, gracias